# Find algebraic multiplicities of $2\times2$ matrix with two distinct solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

I found that the eigenvalues are one and three.

Is the algebraic multiplicity of the real eigenvalues one?

Comment: If $1$ and $3$ are the two eigenvalues, then the characteristic polynomial has to be $(x-1)(x-3)$ because it must be a degree two. So the algebraic multiplicities are $1$ for both eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

The algebraic multiplicity is the exponent of the eigenvalue in the characteristic polynomial. In this case, it's 1